# Best way to find decile/quartile in Fortran?

Tags: fortran

I wish to know an efficient way to find decile/bucket/group in fortran code.

if I have an array (1 :  totaldatacount) with weights(LB) data like...

```
120
140
200
134
185
.
.
.
```

I wish to get 3 groups with break points in 30% and 70%.

What I did was sorting an array then assign  break points based on total number of data.

1st breakpoint:  total data count * 0.3  //
2nd breakpoint:  total data count * 0.7

Thus, first group (1-30) gets array(1:totaldata*0.3)

Second group (31-70) gets array(totaldata*0.3 +1 : totaldata*0.7)

Third group (71-100) gets array(totaldata*0.7+1 : totaldata)

Does this make sense? Does anyone have a code for creating 3 buckets(sorted)?

Comment: What you have described seems straightforward and (if you've chosen your sort routine well) efficient (enough).  So, yes it makes sense.  And you already have your own code.  So what remains of your question ?

Comment: I was wondering if there's any prebuilt functions for this...
If not, then I guess I would go with my method describe above

Comment: There is certainly no Fortran intrinsic routine for solving your problem and I see that no one has come forward with the code that you seek.